# Wordpress adding files to [wpdm_all_packages]

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-shortcode, divi

What i want to is to add files that exist in the wp download manager.

What i tried

```php
[wpdm_all_packages  thumb=1 items_per_page="20" categories="slug1,slug2,..." jstable=1 order_by="field_name" order="ASC/DESC" cols="title,file_count,download_count|categories|update_date|download_link" colheads="Title|Categories|Update Date|Download::155px"]
```

This result in a empty download module.

What i get:
[image]

what i want:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

This worked

[wpdm_all_packages  thumb=1 items_per_page="20" categories="Enter here and it will work" jstable=1 order_by="field_name" order="ASC/DESC" cols="title,file_count,download_count|categories|update_date|download_link" colheads="Title|Categories|Update Date|Download::155px"]